# How to adjust problem when generating graph in R

Tags: r

I don't understand why I can't generate my graph for the `CDE` Code, can you help me solve it? See that for the `ABC` Code it works normally.

Executable code below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


dmda<-"2021-07-07"

datas <- structure(
  list(Code = c("ABC","ABC","ABC","CDE","CDE","CDE"),
       Days = c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
       Numbers = c(11,17,3,2,2,2)),
     class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

  
  f1 <- function(dat, code_nm) {
    dat <- subset(dat,  Code == code_nm)
    
    plot(Numbers ~ Days,  xlim= c(0,7), ylim= c(0,30),
         xaxs='i',data = dat,main = paste0(dmda, "-", code_nm))
    
    model <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0),data = dat, algorithm = "port")
    
    new.data <- data.frame(Days = with(dat, seq(min(Days),max(Days),len = 45)))
    new.data <- rbind(0, new.data)
    lines(new.data$Days,predict(model,newdata = new.data),lwd=2)
    coef<-coef(model)[2]
    points(0, coef, col="red",pch=19,cex = 2,xpd=TRUE)
    text(.99,coef + 1,round(coef,1), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")
  }
  
  f1(datas, "ABC")

  f1(datas, "CDE")
  Error in nls(Numbers ~ b1 * Days^2 + b2, start = list(b1 = 0, b2 = 0),  : 
  Convergence failure: singular convergence (7)
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zm1AY.png]

**Example**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. For `CDE`, all `Numbers` are `2`. So it does not work. If one of `2`'s become 3, it will work. For example, using data below,

```
  Code Days Numbers
1  ABC    1      11
2  ABC    2      17
3  ABC    3       3
4  CDE    1       2
5  CDE    2       2
6  CDE    3       3
```

[image]

```
f1 <- function(dat, code_nm) {
  dat <- subset(dat,  Code == code_nm)
  
  plot(Numbers ~ Days,  xlim= c(0,7), ylim= c(0,30),
       xaxs='i',data = dat,main = paste0(dmda, "-", code_nm))
  if (var(dat$Numbers)>0){
  
  model <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0),data = dat, algorithm = "port")
  
  new.data <- data.frame(Days = with(dat, seq(min(Days),max(Days),len = 45)))
  new.data <- rbind(0, new.data)
  lines(new.data$Days,predict(model,newdata = new.data),lwd=2)
  coef<-coef(model)[2]
  points(0, coef, col="red",pch=19,cex = 2,xpd=TRUE)
  text(.99,coef + 1,round(coef,1), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")} else {
    yz <- unique(dat$Numbers)
    lines(c(0,dat$Days), c(yz, dat$Numbers), lwd = 2)
    points(0, yz, col = "red", pch = 19, cex = 2, xpd = TRUE)
    text(.1,yz+ .5,round(yz,1), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")
  }
  
}

f1(datas, "CDE")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Park!  However, in this case for me, it had to be a horizontal line up to 2, don't you think? Because I can't change it to 3 since it's number 2.

Comment: @JVieira I'll make simple exception. Please wait for a sec.

Comment: @JVieira I add code above.

Comment: @JVieira It's simple by adding `text(.1,yz+ .5,round(yz,1), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")`. Take a look at code edited above.

Comment: Park, last question: You can leave the image as the one I inserted as an example in the question. Note that the horizontal line is only going to the last point.

Comment: @JVieira I edit my code, not an image. `lines(c(0,dat$Days), c(yz, dat$Numbers), lwd = 2)` part is changed.

Comment: Park, just  one thing: could explain a little better that `if` and `else` you entered. It's just for me to understand better.

Comment: @JVieira In `if` part, the condition `var()>0` means not all values are same, that there is no problem to fitting `nls`. `Else` case is that `var() = 0` so it means every values are having same values. If you need more explanation about this, please let me know :D

Comment: Park, please can look this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69532680/graph-is-not-generated-if-i-consider-the-else-if-condition It is similiar to this one.

Comment: @JVieira I'll take a look at that question.